# Leuven Theme makes org-mode headline too big

Tags: org-mode, themes

[image]

As you can see, switching to the leuven theme makes my org-mode first level headlines bigger than the rest of the text. I don't like that, where can I change this behaviour? Where is the leuven-code that takes care of this modification? Is this even caused by the leuven theme?

The reason why I don't like this feature is that I'm using my own "first level headline" (see *Allgemeines*). So as an additional feature: How can I make my own Headings bigger instead of the org-mode headlines? (Maybe the answer to the first question will answer this question too.)

Thanks!

P.S.: I don't want to change the leuven theme, because I like the colors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabrice added a variable for this not too long ago: `leuven-scale-outline-headlines`.

Most importantly, you'll have to set it to `nil` before the theme is loaded. One way to do that is to it through `M-x customize-variable` and then restart Emacs.

Comment: Thank you, this is even better than changing the org-faces, because it eliminates the root-cause. :-)

Comment: How do I make the change in the init.el file? the syntax please.

Answer (score 2):

The code is in `leuven-theme.el` in `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.5/etc/themes` dir (if you use linux and version 24.5). I don't know the path for Windows.

To change the org headlines:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-faces` <kbd>RET</kbd>, then scroll to *Org Level 1*, click on the arrow and then on *Show All Attributes*. Change the `height`, go to the beginning of the buffer and click **Apply**. Repeat until you are happy with the result and then **Apply and Save**.

These changes will be saved in your `custom-file`. To see the path for this file <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `custom-file`. You can also edit it manually but this is discouraged.

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Good to know that I don't have to skim through the `leuven-theme.el` and it is accessible through a menu. Then I'll go on to find out how to highlight my real headings. Thanks for your help! :-)